# Scorm activity - return to the last page visited not working in Firefox - Javascript issue?

Tags: javascript, firefox, moodle, scorm, scorm1.2

I'm using Moodle as a platform to hold SCORM packages. In one of the packages we have a feature, where if a user exits the activity and re-enters they return to the screen they were last on. However, when I click 'ok' to the alert asking if you want to continue from where you left off, Firefox returns a blank screen.

I opened Firefox web console and it found two javascript errors:

```
x Scriptloaded is not defined
x map is null
```

The map is null error points to this piece of code:

```
window.onload = function() { map.PageLoaded(); }
```

**Anyone familiar with this problem?** It only happens in Firefox.

Comment: You have to go deeper and see what is this `map`, where it is defined and why it is null. I don't think anyone can answer this before seeing the actual code.

Comment: Hi there, could someone please help me with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46008375/cannot-retrieve-previously-saved-data-from-lms-scorm-2004) question/issue about SCORM 2004? Thanks in advance.