# Cannot retrieve previously saved data from LMS - SCORM 2004

Tags: javascript, moodle, scorm, scorm2004

I'm trying to retrieve previously saved data from Moodle LMS but seems like something is not working. This is what I'm doing:

I load the SCORM (v2004) package into Moodle and perform some actions (like save navigation data or set completion status):

```
// Completion status always "unknown" at first time so I try to change it to incomplete:
API_1484_11.SetValue('cmi.completion_status', 'incomplete'); // "true"
...
API_1484_11.SetValue('cmi.location', '{"page":2}'); // "true"
```

Then later on commit these changes:

```
API_1484_11.Commit(''); // true
```

Request/Response:

[image: Request]

[image: Response]

When I leave and reenter the activity and try to retrieve this data again the API returns an empty string or the default initial value.

```
// I've already initialized the API at this point.
API_1484_11.GetValue('cmi.completion_status'); // "unknown"
...
API_1484_11.GetValue('cmi.location'); // ""
```

Am I missing something?

Do I need to call any other method to retrieve data from the server or something like that?

Or maybe I misunderstood the purpose of those methods?

I would appreciate any help on this topic. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commit is important.  Make sure you are setting cmi.exit to "suspend".  SCORM 2004 in moodle isn't probably full featured unless someone finished it.  Last I heard the Dev working on it gave up.  So you may be dealing with a SCORM 1.2 implementation.  I'm on a mobile device so I hope that gives you enough hints to troubleshoot.  Good luck.

Comment: Awesome. There are some 3rd party options for 2004 support on moodle. But if you are just performing basic "I was here" content it should work fine.